# Как сделать отправку сообщение в chat_id каждые 15 минут?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time
import json, requests, hashlib, time, re, urllib.request, os, pymysql

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='XXXXXXXX')
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
chat_id = session_api.messages.searchConversations(q='Chat_BotInfo(Beta)', count=1)['items'][0]['peer']['local_id']
print(chat_id)

while(True):
    session_api.messages.send("chat_id": 6,{"message":"Привет!!!", "random_id":123456})
    time.sleep(900)
```

Ошибка:

```
File "test1.py", line 14
session_api.messages.send("chat_id": 6,{"message":"Привет!!!", "random_id":123456})
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Как сделать отправку сообщение в chat_id каждые 15 минут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Говорится про `SyntaxError`.

```
...("chat_id": 6,...
```

Почему тут ключ-значение вне словаря?

Я не использовал встроенные методы библиотеки, поэтому точно сказать не могу, но попробуйте:

```
vk_session.method("messages.send", {"chat_id": 6, "message": "lolkek", "random_id": 123456})
```